# what does the PadRight function do in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

For this line of code I'm having trouble visualizing what the `padright` function does?

```
results = Transpose[PadRight[{RMSL, MaxDevL, AreaofeachTorsoL, NormalxLp2, 
     NormalyLp2, NormalzLp2, TorsoLp, RMSLn, MaxDevLn, 
     AreaofeachTorsoLn, NormalxLn2, NormalyLn2, NormalzLn2, 
     TorsoLn}, {Colnu, Rownu2}, P]];
```

Comment: The documentation here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html shows exactly what the PadRight function does. If, for example you try `PadRight[{a,b,c},5]` then it will append extra zeros onto the end of that list until it is of length 5 giving the result `{a,b,c,0,0}` But your code looks like it contains some or perhaps all vectors and matricies along with some constants and we have no idea what those values are. So it is difficult to guess what it will do without more information. Can you give more information about the contents or shape of the values of all those symbols?

Answer (score 0):

You need Join 2 number in XXXXX and  PPPPP ,such as

XXXXX = 16; PPPP = 2;
results =
Transpose[
PadRight[{RMSL, MaxDevL, AreaofeachTorsoL, NormalxLp2, NormalyLp2,
NormalzLp2, TorsoLp, RMSLn, MaxDevLn, AreaofeachTorsoLn,
NormalxLn2, NormalyLn2, NormalzLn2, TorsoLn},
XXXXX, {Colnu, Rownu2}, PPPP]]

Comment: Please consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your answer properly to help understand it better